# What form of the verb is used with a subject like "little me"?

Tags: subject-verb-agreement, personal-pronouns, third-person-singular

I want to say that I look innocent in an old picture of mine and I don't know if I should say:

- "Little me looks so innocent"; or
- "Little me look so innocent" (*without an "s"*)

Comment: You are treating 'little me' as a different person, so 'he or she'.

Comment: You are referring to yourself in the third person, the same as if you used your name instead of "I", so "looks" is correct.

Comment: I don't think this is the way "little me" is normally used: it's most common as a direct or indirect object, or as a vocative or form of address. Also it sound old-fashioned, although NGrams shows a rise in popularity in recent years after lagging through the 20th century. I'd prefer: "Poor little me, I look so innocent."